# SQL Server - Unable to create database in Symfony 3

Tags: php, sql-server, symfony

I am using Symfony for quite sometime now, and I have no trouble in connections in Mysql database, until I decided to use Microsoft SQL server as  the database.

This is how I configure my paramters.yml

parameters:

```
#database_host: 127.0.0.1
database_host: MENGGAY//SQL server tells it is the host name 
database_port: null
database_name: Paycom
database_user: MENGGAY\ian
database_password: ~
mailer_transport: smtp
mailer_host: 127.0.0.1
mailer_user: null
mailer_password: null
secret: ThisTokenIsNotSoSecretChangeIt
```

config.yml

```
doctrine:
dbal:
    driver_class: Realestate\MssqlBundle\Driver\PDODblib\Driver 
    host:     "%database_host%"
    port:     "%database_port%"
    dbname:   "%database_name%"
    user:     "%database_user%"
    password: "%database_password%"
    charset:  UTF8
```

I am using bundle here

```
    "realestateconz/mssql-bundle": "master-dev"
```

And of course pdo_sqlsrv already installed,  I am using WAMP here.

When I run

```
  php bin/console doctrine:database:create
```

got an error

> Could not create database [Paycom] for connection named
>    default
>   Notice: Undefined property: Doctrine\DBAL\Connection::$options

Symfony.com says it does support Ms SQL Server, however it does not provide exact guide how to configure parameters.yml for the Ms SQL server

SQL server successfully running in my windows machine
Any guide to connect this succesfully? Any Ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You use a custom MsSQL driver, so that's not a symfony problem.

Have you tried with clean `pdo_sqlsrv` driver?

MssqlBundle is not maintained anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Solve

First by fixing the parameters.yml

```
 database_host: MENGGAY\SQLEXPRESS
```

Notice the backlash \ and SQLEXPRESS

Next in config.yml

```
 driver_class: pdo_sqlsrv
```

I am using WAMP, so I have to make sure pdo_sqlsrv is enabled and added the pdo_sqlsrv in php.ini, again by clicking the WAMP icon

Well it is enabled, but it does not show up when running

```
 <?php info(); ?>
```

Thus returning an error

> driver not found

The trick is

Go to your project folder

In commandline, I am using Gitbash here

```
cd c:/wamp/www/MyProject


php --ini
```

Now this will point me where to put pdo_sqlsrv.dll to the right php.ini file

Move pdo_sqlsrv.dll to the right php.ini

Restart WAMP

run again

```
   php bin/console doctrine:database:create
```

And hoola, success!